# Rumble Roller question

Tags: muscle

Recently I bought a rumble roller.

I use it primarily for Hamstring and Quads muscles.

Is it safe to use it 3-4 times a week ?
How much times a week it is recommended to use a rumble roller ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the rumbler anywhere you'd normally foam roll. But there are places that will hurt more than others, and with a rumbler, it might be even worse. But that doesn't necessarily make it a bad idea. In fact, most of the time, the places that really hurt, are the ones that need it the most.

3-4 times a week sounds good. I don't think there is a specific guideline for how often you should and shouldn't use it. And even if there was, we're all different. You should start with whatever feels natural, and "listen to your body". It will often tell you if you've overdone it, or if it feels so good that you should do it more often.